# Delete rows if column ID is same

Tags: r, rows, tabular

I am relatively new to **R**. I have the Table 1 below. How can I obtain the Output table below. Any suggestions?

```
Table 1:

YEAR  COUNTY  Ref  Pred   N     Accuracy  Overall  AccOne  AccTwo
2010     1     0    0    5472     81.0      0        0       0
2010     1     0    0    472      81.0      0        0       0
2010     1     0    0    1472     81.0      0        0       0
2010     1     0    0    54       81.0      0        0       0
2010     1     0    0    5        81.0      21.4     0       0
2010     1     0    0    572      81.0      0        0       0
2010     1     0    0    472      81.0      0        12.3    0
2010     1     0    0    54       81.0      0        0       74.4
2010     101   0    0    5472     91.0      0        0       0
2010     101   0    0    472      91.0      0        0       0
2010     101   0    0    1472     91.0      0        0       0
2010     101   0    0    54       91.0      0        0       0
2010     101   0    0    5        91.0      100     0        0
2010     101   0    0    572      91.0      0        0       0
2010     101   0    0    472      91.0      0        NaN     0
2010     101   0    0    54       91.0      0        0       NaN


Output:
    2010     1       0    0    5472     81.0      21.4     12.3    74.4
    2010     101     0    0    472      91.0      100       NaN     NaN
```

Comment: What is an identical "column id" here? We can guess why you specifically choose the output table but it would be helpful if you tell us exactly what you are expecting. For example it seems that Overall, AccOne, and AccTwo are consolidated by Year. Or how in year 2010, county 101, you use N of 472? Why 472? Please give just a little bit more detail.

Comment: Also, it would be extra helpful if you provided the data in a format that we can easily load onto our own computer to work with. Perhaps use `dput(Table1)` and edit your question with the results.